# JSON error on using jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, datatables

```
[{"name":"aaa","firstname":"bbb","lastname":"ccc"},
{"name":"qqq","firstname":"eee","lastname":"mmm"},
{"name":"www","firstname":"ooo","lastname":"lll"}]
```

> I am making ajax request to server, its returning the above json data.But i >am getting the json parse error

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
                "url": "http://example",
                "dataType": "jsonp",
        "columns": [
                { "data": "name"},
                { "data": "firstname" },
                { "data": "lastname" }
            ]
            }
        } );
});
```

Comment: is this the right way to assign columns ?http://www.datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html

Comment: @RohanKumar, well - he **is** getting a result back, and using jsonp .... So no, has nothing to do with Same-origin policy.

Comment: Yes, it looks much better now :) have deleted the answer.

Comment: DataTables warning: table id=example - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

Comment: The data you have is not JSONP.

Comment: @Quentin - eehh, what is correct JSONP data then? How does JSONP differ from other AJAX sources?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ajax attribute should not contain the column attribute.:

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
                "url": "http://example",
                "dataType": "jsonp"
        },
        "columns": [
                 { "data": "name"},
                 { "data": "firstname" },
                 { "data": "lastname" }
            ]
        } );
});
```

Comment: If i remove jsonp, i am getting Same origin policy error

Comment: @GirishMahindrakar, ok for same origin policy can be added like that, however your ajax and columns where overlapping which I have shown in the answer

Comment: +1. Good spot. I also think this is the correct answer. @GirishMahindrakar, you have simply malformed initialization options :)